# How to setup docker in Jenkins?

Tags: docker, jenkins

My question is on how to setup docker in jenkins
We have one master server and 5 linux slaves and 2 windows slaves
We are using artifactory to store docker images.

What would be the steps to intergrate docker **in** jenkins ? Do I need to install docker on linux and windows slaves or any plugin installation required?

There are a lot of plugins: - docker plugin - docker build step plugin - docker pipeline plugin

Which of these can be useful?

I am naive to docker and have no idea on how to proceed with it.

Comment: What do you mean by integrate? Do you want to build docker images from Jenkins? You want to run containers on Jenkins, or keep repository of images?

In any case during work with Jenkins I use pipelines - it is more powerful than any plugin, you have control over everything.

Comment: Do you want to build docker images from Jenkins? - YES, so I just need to install docker on slaves ?

Comment: It depends. How do you build it now? Using docker commands? Using system build plugins like maven to build images? Where do you want to move the build part - to slaves only? If so, the slaves should know docker. I can't help you with setting the plugins as i'm not using them. I have standard docker commands on my pipelne. I dont even know if you use pipeline or just plugins.

Comment: We do not build docker images as of now. This is what i am trying to implement.All our build jobs run on slaves.We are using pipelines.To run docker commands on pipeline I just need to install docker on slaves right ? Also, I have RHEL7.3 on slaves, docker CE doesnt support RHEL ?

Comment: Yes, if job is run on slave it is enough to install docker there. You have to check the compaibility by yourself.

Comment: Did you install docker rpm created by official docker or did you create your own rpm to install it on the slaves ?

Comment: @h__ Did you also install docker pipeline plugin ? I installed docker on my slaves and ran docker command using pipelines and it worked. I was wondering why here https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/ under toggle scripted pipeline, it says "Requires the Docker Pipeline plugin to be installed" , any idea why ?

Comment: I use the old pipelines and I integrated docker manually. This plugin allow you to move part of operation into groovy script instead of running everything from shell level